# Helmholtz operator fundamental solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

How can I find the fundamental solution to the following PDE in $R^3$:

$$-\Delta + 1 = 0$$.

So far I have that $\hat{u} = \frac{1}{1-|s|^2}$, but how can i get the inverse FT in 3D. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235615/fundamental-solution-of-the-helmholtz-equation?

Comment: @user293794 its different than mine.

Comment: I think there should be a plus sign instead of a minus sign in your expression for $\hat u.$

Comment: @md2perpe why so?

Comment: Because under the Fourier transform, $\Delta$ transforms to $-|s|^2$ while $1$ stays unchanged. So $\mathcal{F}\{-\Delta+1\} = -(-|s|^2)+1 = |s|^2+1.$

Comment: where did the "-" come into outside the parentheses? @md2perpe which property of FT is that?

Comment: @BrazyOski Look at the accepted answer: Mark Viola computes the inverse Fourier transform of a function which is the negative of what you want, with $k=1$.

Comment: @user293794 what do you mean negative? that is entirely different since the solution is $e^(ikr)/4\pi r$

Comment: The minus sign outside of the parentheses is the minus sign in $-\Delta.$ The minus sign inside of the parentheses comes from the Fourier transform; $\nabla$ transforms to $i\mathbf{s}$ so $\Delta=\nabla^2$ transforms to $(i\mathbf{s})^2 = -|s|^2.$

Comment: okay i see much appreciate it @md2perpe